# A-Frame local image is not loading

Tags: aframe

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/b813db0614ac2b518e547105e810b5b6eccfe1c8/dist/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('set-sky', {
        schema: {default: ''},
        init() {
          const sky = document.querySelector('a-sky');
          this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            sky.setAttribute('src', this.data);
          });
        }
      });
    </script>

    <a-scene>
      <a-camera position="0 2 4">
        <a-cursor color="#4CC3D9" fuse="true" timeout="10"></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>

      <a-sphere color="#F44336" radius="1" position="-4 2 0" set-sky="https://c3.staticflickr.com/2/1475/26239222850_cabde81c39_k.jpg"></a-sphere>

      <a-sphere color="#FFEB3B" radius="1" position="4 2 0" set-sky="32252838043_e8f2be6783_k.jpeg"></a-sphere>

      <a-sky></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to a-frame, have not worked much in java script either. The code above works fine for the referenced image, but does not work for the local image. What is actually i'm doing wrong ? I found this example [here](https://blog.neondaylight.com/build-a-simple-web-vr-ui-with-a-frame-a17a2d5b484#.nsmrp3jln).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are using a local server (e.g., Mongoose, python -m SimpleHTTPServer, or npm install live-server) and that the image is on the same path as your `index.html` given where you're referencing it form.

Comment: Any server like 'Apache' will work or specifically it has to be Mongoose ?

Comment: e.g., as in "For example," so any server will work. I mean local development servers though. Apache is overkill. See the A-Frame getting started guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.cesanta.com/products/binary, it's easy to use. No configuring of server structure in any way needed.